# Windows 8, brand new computer, slow internet

Tags: windows-8, laptop, performance, internet, reboot

If I close the lid on my new Windows 8 laptop, the internet is sporadic, sometimes it loads fully, most of the time it acts like it looses the wireless connection and wont load anything. I have tried Explorer and Firefox. I have AVG installed and running scans daily. When I restart the laptop it runs like a champ. No difficulty at all. I just can't close the lid without restarting it...Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: When you close the lid... Do you mean this occurs when you re-open the lid or are you using an external monitor ? or are you only part closing the lid due to what ever reason?

Comment: I think he means when he sleeps/hibernates it. That is the default behavior of closing the lid anyways.

Comment: check if the system is deactivating the eth/wlan due to system innactivity. it might be it

Comment: He is most likely a she, btw... I don't know many dudes named Catherine.

Comment: woops. could be a fake name?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming wireless: Click start, type power, and open power options. Then click change plan settings. In plan settings, verify this:

[image: change plan settings]

For wired: Click start, type network, and open network and sharing center. Then click change adapter settings and right click on your adapter that is in use. Click properties and on that menu, click configure. In the configure panel, you may be able to change/verify power management settings specific to your adapter. It is different per adapter; ie, I have an intel NIC which offers different capabilities.

Choosing maximum performance while in sleep mode should at the very least confirm whether or not it's a 'wake' issue or something else.